# Maven-JSF Primefaces EL nullPointerException relating to the primefaces balises

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, primefaces, el

I have some .xhtml hsf pages in which I'm using primefaces and the EL, when trying to do something retating to those pages I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`that I think it's because I can't get relating EL expressions that I have inside my xhtml files :

```
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    ....
javax.faces.FacesException: #{userMB.addUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
```

I think the problem is not in the EL dependencies because I already use it in other jsf files without the primefaces balises, an other thing that confirm that is that eclipse underline the declaration of `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` and all the balises like `<td><p:inputText id="name" value="#{userMB.name}">` which containes the EL declarations. However I added the primefaces exactly into the project's pom.xml :

```
<!-- Primefaces library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
    <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>  
    <version>1.0.6</version>  
    </dependency> 
...
<repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
```

I can acces to all the jsf pages correctly except those containing the primefaces 'p:' declarations which are userlined by eclipse.

I m not realy sure that I understand the exception so there is a compete snapshot of it :

```
 Jul 27, 2012 2:44:27 AM com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl processAction
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stage.beans.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 20 more

Jul 27, 2012 2:44:27 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{userMB.addUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{userMB.addUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stage.beans.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 20 more
```

I m pretty shure that I configure exaclty my configuration files but this is some snapshots of them :

from my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
            <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
          </listener>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
```

from my faces-config.xml :

```
<application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
```

thank you for help

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem.  You mean you have added the dependency but the dependency doesn't appear in the final war?  Or you can see the dependency in the final war but certain feature depending on that lib is not working?

Comment: Just read the bottommost "Caused by" part for the main root cause.

Comment: Sorry for my first comment, I just restart eclipse and all dependences are now included in my buildpath, the problem that I have is that I can't get the values that I enter in fields like <p:inputText id="id" value="#{userMB.id}"> so I get the nullPointerException when triying to get the values from my managed beand (userMB)

Comment: yes Mr.BalusC, I now that I have a nullPointerException , but I can't really figure out what is the cause, in fact the EL configuration is setted well in my project, thank you fo help

Comment: This has completely nothing to do with EL configuration. Why don't you just look at line 58 of UserManagedBean what exactly is `null` while you're attempting to access/invoke it and thus causing the NPE?

Comment: in this line I should get what the user enter from the navigator, for example his name, password..., the problem is that I can't get those attributes because I have something wrong with my EL